# How Do I Make My Menu Make A Beep/Bell Sound When It is Ready to Take the User's Input (UNIX)

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I am trying to add some sort of echo command to make my menu make a beep or bell sound when it is ready for the user's input. I'd appreciate any possible help, thank you!

```
loop=y
while [ "$loop" = y ]
do
 clear
  tput cup 3 12; echo "Soup Menu"
  tput cup 4 12; echo "=========="
  tput cup 6 9; echo "(t)omato"
  tput cup 7 9; echo "(b)ean"
  tput cup 8 9; echo "(s)quash"
  tput cup 10 9; echo "Select a soup...(q) to quit"
  tput cup 10 19;
  read choice || continue
done
```

Comment: [ASCII 7](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/2299-how-to-emit-a-beep-by-printing-the-ascii-bell-character-to-the-console.html)

Comment: `echo ^G` may work. Where Ctrl-G is create by pressing the Ctrl Key and the G Key at the same time. Good luck.

Comment: You may also want to consider using tools like [dialog](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) or [whiptail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) instead of rolling your own menu system.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example, that would be

```
tput bel
```

The [`terminfo(5)`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual says, giving the long name (bell), and short name (bel) which would be used by [`tput`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html):

```
   bell                          bel        bl        audible signal
                                                      (bell) (P)
```